# Where did Whitfield Diffie say "If you can make random numbers, you can have a private conversation"?

Tags: reference-request, entropy

I've seen the following (alleged) quotation on [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/92197/23115) site and  [other](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2019/07/yubico_security.html/#comment-337699) places:-

> If you can make random numbers, you can have a private conversation.

-Whitfield Diffie.

Yet we (Google & me) can't find an original source for it.  Can anyone point me to the original publication/talk/presentation? Or is it just folklore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That quote is an offhand comment that Whitfield Diffie made during a lecture that was, and perhaps still is, on YouTube.  It is accurate.

A similar quote can be found in the YouTube video entitled "Stanford Seminar- Cryptography and Security: The View from 2016".  It begins around 29:30.

Whitfield Diffie said:

> "If you can manufacture good keys, you can have secure cryptography.
> You might have to manufacture a lot of key, what's called one-time
> material... it is logically possible to have secure cryptography if
> you can make secure keys..."

Comment: You're right - the summary statement reads a lot better than the one from 2016.